# PyQt4 - Phonon - Mac build issue

Tags: macos, pyqt4, phonon

I am having a problem with Phonon in PyQt and was wondering whether anybody else had come across it. I have built SIP and PyQt with Qt 4.8 successfully from these sources:

**Qt Libraries**
qt-mac-opensource-4.8.5.dmg
**Sip**
sip-4.15.1
**PyQt**
PyQt-mac-gpl-4.10.3

I can import and use the PyQt modules fine except for Phonon. When I try to import Phonon with:

```
from PyQt4 import Phonon
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Volumes/SYSTEM/Python_Environment/Python2.7/MAC/codebase-django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/phonon.so, 
2): Symbol not found: __ZN6Phonon22ObjectDescriptionModelILNS_21ObjectDescriptionTypeE0EE11qt_metacastEPKc
Referenced from: /Volumes/SYSTEM/Python_Environment/Python2.7/MAC/codebase-django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/phonon.so
Expected in: flat namespace
in /Volumes/SYSTEM/Python_Environment/Python2.7/MAC/codebase-django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/phonon.so
```

Has anybody come across this and is there a solution? I am trying to avoid MacPort and Homebrew if possible.

Comment: How did you install ad build Phonon? (I would use Homebrew or Macports as they would have already found the issue)

Answer (score 1):

I've found this bug report https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-37209, I hope this will be solved with Qt 4.8.7.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I gave up and went to Macports which worked.

I installed the PyQt4 from Macports and then copied the PyQt folders from stie-packages into my virtualenv. I also copied over the Sip files.